# create a pipe with a tee for both stderr and stdout in shell

Tags: shell, pipe, io-redirection

In `bash`, I am able to create a pipe for both stderr and stdout that I connect to a tee.
But because of application constrains, I have to do it in shell (simple `sh`).
And I don't know how to workaround these simple redirections.

Here is a simple example working in `bash` but not in `sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

gcc &> >(tee toto.txt) && echo 'ok' || echo 'oups'

gcc --version &> >(tee -a toto.txt) && echo 'ok' || echo 'oups'
```

The point is to have an equivalent to `&> >(tee )` in sh.
The extra `echo` are just to check that the stdout and stderr remains available.
Because the solution of injecting the stderr in the stdout and piping it (`2>&1 | tee`), is in a way killing the stderr (ie. `echo 'oups'` will never occurs).
In other words, keeping the stderr and stdout are also parts of my application contrains.

Comment: you can manage pipes yourself with [`mkfifo`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mkfifo.html)

Comment: by the way, streaming your stderr to a file has nothing to do with the exit code that determines which echo fires.